# Disable NonInteractiveExampleWarning in python hypothesis

Tags: python, hypothesis-test

I want to use `hypothesis` awesome features to create some sample data for my application. I use it roughly like this

```
from hypothesis import strategies as st

ints = st.integers()  #simplified example
ints.example()
```

I get this warning:

> NonInteractiveExampleWarning: The `.example()` method is good for exploring strategies, but should only be used interactively

Is there a simple way to disable this warning? Just to be clear: I want to use the example data generation outside of a testing and in a non-interactive context and I'm aware of what the warning is referring to. I just want to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/warnings.html) module lets you selectively ignore specific warnings; for example:

```py
from hypothesis.errors import NonInteractiveExampleWarning
from hypothesis import strategies as st
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=NonInteractiveExampleWarning)

    ints = st.integers()
    print( ints.example() )
```